# Determine if button is inside contour

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a PictureBox on which a contour is drawn. Let's say this contour is in form of a circle. Now when I click a button a lot of buttons are created over the PictureBox row by row until the PictureBox is full:

```
For n As Integer = 1 To buttonNumberY
    For m As Integer = 1 To buttonNumerX
        Dim Btn As New Button
        Btn.Width = elementsize
        Btn.Height = elementsize
        Btn.Flatstyle = Flatstyle:Flat
        Btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1
        Btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Gray
        Btn.Location = new Point(elementsize*(m-1)+BORDER, maxContourHeight * scaley + BORDER - elementsize * n)
        Btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Btn.Name = "Btn" & m & n
        PictureBox1.Controls.Add(Btn)
    Next
Next
```

As true transparency doesn't exist in WinForms I used some code so that the contour will be visible through the small buttons lying over the PictureBox (thanks for the help with this problem :)).

Now I have to determine whether a button is inside the contour or outside. I already have an idea of how to do this:

- In a For Next loop every button should be checked if it has been painted.
- If yes, it is partially inside the contour.
- If no I have to check whether one of all the buttons under this one (in y direction) is painted.
- If none of the buttons below this one is painted then it is not inside the contour.
- If only one button below is painted then it is inside the contour and if two buttons are painted then it is outside of the contour again.

The problem I have is the following:

1. How can I check if a button is painted or not?
2. All the small buttons are generated through the code. Can I actually write code to check these buttons by referring to their name when they don't even exist yet in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it sounds like you want to check if a point is within a circle, mathematically speaking this would be the algorithm:

```
(point.x - center.x) ^ 2 + (point.y - center.y) ^ 2 < radius ^ 2
```

In terms of your two questions, the button would be painted after you create the control. Probably not immediately, but you can force the control to be repainted dynamically by refreshing the parent.

Since you're setting the Button's name, then you could use the Form.Controls.Find method and set the *searchAllChildren* parameter to `True`.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your help. The problem is that the contour is a bit more complex than the circle. I put the contour together with around 20 lines of code. Therefore I just wanted to check if the button is painted or not. Any idea of how to do this?